# Temporary save sender (ActorRef) to reply it later

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Temporary save sender to reply later

I have a 3 actors

```
class Actor1 extends Actor {
  val actor2 = context actorOf (Props[Actor2])
  actor2 ! Actor2Request

  def receive = {
    case data: String => // need to receive it
  }
}

class Actor2 extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case Actor2Request =>
      //sender is Actor1 but I want to save it now and reply it later on in "case DoneActor3(data: String)"
      val actor3 = context actorOf (Props[Actor3])
      actor3 ! Actor3Request

    case DoneActor3(data: String) =>
      // doing something with data
      // and then send it to Actor1
      sender ! data //ops! sender is Actor3 now, not Actor1!
  }
}

class Actor3 extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case Actor3Request =>
      //doing some work...
      sender ! DoneActor3(data) // sender is Actor2 and that's ok! 
  }
}
```

Take a look at `Actor2` code, I want to save `sender` (**Actor1**) when it receives `Actor2Request` message and reply to this `sender` later when `Actor2` receives   `DoneActor3(data: String)` message.

Is there an idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `forward`, which preserves the original sender when passing messages between actors.
In this case, you don't even need to send the return data via `Actor2`

```
class Actor2 extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Actor2Request =>
      val actor3 = context actorOf (Props[Actor3])
      //sender will still be actor1 when actor3 receives this forwarded message
      actor3 forward Actor3Request
  }
}

class Actor3 extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Actor3Request =>
      //doing some work...
      sender ! data // sender is actor1
  }
}
```

If you *do* need to return via `Actor2`, perhaps for some intermediate processing, then you want to capture the original sender and pass it via the actor messages:

```
class Actor2 extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Actor2Request =>
      val actor3 = context actorOf (Props[Actor3])
      //sender at this point is actor1
      actor3 ! Actor3Request(sender)

    case DoneActor3(origin, data) =>
      // Do some other stuff here
      origin ! data //origin is the original sender as passed to Actor3Request
  }
}

class Actor3 extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Actor3Request(origin) =>
      //doing some work...
      sender ! DoneActor3(origin, data) // origin is actor1, sender is actor2
  }
}
```

Or you can mix & match the techniques, having `Actor3` send a message direct to `origin`

**UPDATE**

There's one final solution, which is valid here because `actor2` was created by `actor1`.  In this case we know that `actor1` will be the parent of `actor2` in the supervision hierarchy:

```
class Actor2 extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Actor2Request =>
      val actor3 = context actorOf (Props[Actor3])
      actor3 ! Actor3Request

    case DoneActor3(data) =>
      // Do some other stuff here
      context.parent ! data //context.parent is actor1
  }
}

class Actor3 extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Actor3Request =>
      //doing some work...
      sender ! DoneActor3(data) //sender is actor2
  }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at my update at `Actor2.receive.case DoneActor3(data: String) =>` because I've missed something, sorry.

Comment: Your second approach seems what I need.

Comment: I'm not ready because although the second one works it is still kind clumsy, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the `ActorRef` in a `var` and use it later:

```
class Actor2 extends Actor {

  private var requester: ActorRef = _

  def receive = {
    case Actor2Request =>
      requester = sender
      val actor3 = context actorOf (Props[Actor3])
      actor3 ! Actor3Request

    case DoneActor3(data: String) =>
      requester ! data 
  }
}
```

That's what actors are for, keeping track of changing states. I know Scala discourages the usage of `var`, but in the context of actors it's perfectly fine.

Edit for comments: your `Actor2` is created in `Actor1`, there is a one-to-one association between them, so even if you have several instances of `Actor1` they'll each have their own child `Actor2`. I don't know what your goal is with this design, another approach would be to user `parent` instead of `sender` in `Actor2`, that would point to the `Actor1` that created it, or you could pass the `ActorRef` of `Actor1` as an argument of the constructor of `Actor2`.

Comment: won't there be a race condition?

Comment: @alex - Yes, if there are multiple instances of `actor1` then you run a very high risk of hitting a race condition.

Comment: Yes, it'll work here.  I'm still uncomfortable with the pattern though, as it's too fragile in the presence of refactoring (e.g. What if actor1 is changed in the future to be a pool of actors?)

Comment: If `Actor2` gets a message from anybody else while it's waiting for `DoneActor3` then it's going to have problems.

Comment: @sourcedelica, why? sender is stored when a message Actor2Request is received.

Comment: @sourcedelica Not if `requester` is only used for this particular message pair, it won't.

Comment: @Kevin Wright `Yes, if there are multiple instances of actor1 then you run a very high risk of hitting a race condition` - I was thinking of it again and realized that it shouldn't be so. Doesn't an actor handle only one message at a time?